# Select all entries where average is less than specified value

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate, average

I have two SQL tables The first one is called employees and it contains the employee names, the unique employee ids and the department names of a company.

Sample:

```
id  name    department
1   robert  engineering
2   muhammad    sales
3   john    engineering
4   steve   engineering
5   recardo engineering
6   ariel   human-resource
7   lena    human-resource
8   lucy    customer-service
9   barbara testing
10  eli testing
```

The second one is named salaries. It holds the same employee names and the same employee ids – and the salaries for each employee.

Sample:

```
    emp_id  emp_name    salary
1   robert  100
2   muhammad    100
3   john    200
4   steve   200
5   recardo 250
6   riel    250
7   lena    300
8   lucy    100
9   barbara 280
10  eli 265
```

The company has 10 employees, so both tables have 10 rows.

How to print every department where the average salary per employee is lower than $ 203?

DDLs and fiddle of same

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `name`, `department`) VALUES
(1, 'robert', 'engineering'),
(2, 'muhammad', 'sales'),
(3, 'john', 'engineering'),
(4, 'steve', 'engineering'),
(5, 'recardo', 'engineering'),
(6, 'ariel', 'human-resource'),
(7, 'lena', 'human-resource'),
(8, 'lucy', 'customer-service'),
(9, 'barbara', 'testing'),
(10, 'eli', 'testing');

CREATE TABLE `salaries` (
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `emp_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `salary` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `salaries` (`emp_id`, `emp_name`, `salary`) VALUES
(1, 'robert', 100),
(2, 'muhammad', 100),
(3, 'john', 200),
(4, 'steve', 200),
(5, 'recardo', 250),
(6, 'riel', 250),
(7, 'lena', 300),
(8, 'lucy', 100),
(9, 'barbara', 280),
(10, 'eli', 265);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c33f0/2/1

Comment: Note that you wouldn't store the emp_name in salaries table. In fact, you probably wouldn't have a separate salaries table at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a join option.  We can aggregate by department and then assert that a given department's average salary be less than $203.

```
SELECT
    d.department
FROM departments d
INNER JOIN salaries s
    ON d.id = s.emp_id
GROUP BY
    d.department
HAVING
    AVG(s.salary) < 203;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c33f0/8)**

```
SELECT department,avg(salary)
FROM employee a
inner join salaries b on a.id=b.emp_id
group by department
having avg(salary)<203
```